# Expressjs with Laravel api

Tags: node.js, laravel, express, reactjs, reverse-proxy

What is the best way to integrate Expressjs/NodeJs applications with laravel api ?

Details:

I'm using Reactjs and wanna do server side rendering, so I created a nodejs server on port 3000 to render my application on the server side. Now on the backend I have my Laravel api which runs on port 8000. I'm only using Laravel's `api.php` so I need the route `http://my-app/api` to be available to laravel.

what is the best way for my nodejs/express application to connect to my laravel api? should I do reverse proxying ? should I do cross-domain ajax to access my laravel api ?

UPDATE 1:

What I'm trying to achieve is to render my react/redux application in on the server side with nodejs and to manage my api with laravel. and my problem is that when my app is getting served with nodejs on some port, i can't communicate with laravel api running on another port. I'm seeking a workaround for this

Answer (score 0):

This is to general. If you could explain your case, in which you think you would need both technologies "integrated", it might be easier for us to give you some help. How are you going to integrate them and what is the purpose?

Node and Laravel are both server side technologies, using the two in conjunction doesn't really make much sense without a little understanding of what you're trying to accomplish.

What you can do is create two separate apps and give them ability to communicate with each other through API's, via a shared database and/or web services. For example, the laravel website could act as the data warehouse exposing an Restful API that the Node consumes.

If it's real-time communication that you're interested in, then take a look at some of the Websocket technologies that are available for PHP/Laravel as well, such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com), [Socket.io](http://socket.io) or [Laravel Broadcasting and the new Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting).

Comment: That's exactly what i wanna do "use laravel as the data warehouse". but I'm not able to send ajax requests to it, how do I do that if its on another port? i've updated the question